# Comparing logistic regression models using chi-square test for difference in deviance?

Tags: logistic, model-comparison

I have a binary outcome of interest, and I have 9 binary predictors - the predictors are 9 different events having occurred (or not). So I want to ask the question 'did the customer buy anything?', with the predictors of 1) whether or not they got a phone call, 2) a letter, 3) met with representative in a store, etc (clearly they could have had multiples of these evens happen). In the first model, I entered all the predictors as class variables. In model 2 I summed them and entered that summative predictor by itself (reflecting for example, that any person might have been exposed to 0-9 of the 9 things).

I want to compare these models, can I use the chi-square distribution for the difference in -2LL? Some references say the models must be nested (I cant tell if these count as nested or not), while other references only say 'compare deviance between other models fitted in the same data', which these clearly are.

The models do produce very large deviance statistics, and very large differences between them (-2LLmodel1 (-) -2LLmodel2 = 358565, with delta df = 10).

Is this really indicating that the models are meaningfully different in terms of fit? The c-statistics do vary but only on order of about .02-.03.

(I have a very large sample if that makes a difference (>25,000)).

Comment: The models you are comparing do need to be nested for a likelihood ratio test. It doesn't look like your models are nested one within another but you can compare the models using information criteria such as AIC or BIC.